# Сортировка массива

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Здравствуйте есть такой [массив](https://codeo.me/5rO) никак не могу отсортировать его так, что бы ключи qty и qtr находились внизу в зависимости от наименьшего значения, причем qtr должен быть ниже чем qty

пробовал так, но что-то не правильно сортирует

```
usort($this->images, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['qty'] >= $b['qty']) ? -1 : 1;
});

usort($this->images, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['qtr'] >= $b['qtr']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: @dogmar - пожалуйста, приведите пример того, как должен выглядеть массив после "сортировки".

Comment: Обновил ссылку с массивом

Comment: @dogmar - Почему 4 находиться выше 1, а в такой же ситуации, где qtr равны, элементы 0 и 3 в другом порядке идут?

Comment: @ua6xh 4 находится выше 1, потому что у него qty больше, элементы 0 и 3 я поправил, стояли не правильно, от этих сортировок голова закипела:)

Comment: @dogmar - почему до сортировки элемент 2 один:

      2 => array(
        'name'=>'Тест 3',
        'qty'=>'5',
        'qtr'=>'1',
      ),

а после сортировки другой:

      2 => array(
        'name'=>'Тест 3',
        'qty'=>'5',
        'qtr'=>'3',
      ),

?

Comment: Моя невнимательность, поправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        function cmp($a, $b){
            if ($a['qtr'] > $b['qtr']) {
                return -1;
            } elseif(($a['qtr'] == $b['qtr'])) {
                if(($a['qty'] > $b['qty'])) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else{
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

Код на [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/K3YYSQ)